# How can I define series labels in ChartWizard method?

Tags: c#, charts, excel-charts

I'm trying to write a code in C# that creates a chart.

After creating the chart I'm giving it its properties, and having trouble with defining  the `SeriesLabels` in `chart.ChartWizard()` method.

Can you please help me to name each series differently?

Here is the line that I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with it:

```
chart.ChartWizard(Source: some_range, Title: "some title",
    HasLegend: true, SeriesLabels: "" ,Gallery: Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.chart.chartwizard.aspx), describing the `SeriesLabels` parameter:

> An integer specifying the number of rows or columns within the source range that contain series labels. Legal values are from 0 (zero) through one less than the maximum number of the corresponding categories or series.

In other words, that parameter does not do what you seem to think it does. You are required to pass an integer value, not a `string` object. The actual labels themselves need to be in your source data. This parameter just tells the `ChartWizard()` method *where* in the source data to find them.